# How to add a google map which has a slanting edge at one side to an html page?

Tags: html, css

basically,i want to attach a google map to the right side of my contact page but the left edge of the map should be slanting at 30deg rather than being straight,please give ideas.

Comment: My site has such UI. steal code from there - knowkalpesh.in

You need to use pseudo element and apply border to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in comment that you can achieve it using pseudo element (`:before`) and CSS `border`.

I don't know whether it is 30deg or not, but you can tweak it as per your need.

```css
.map-container {
position: relative;
}
.map-container img {
    height: 400px;
    width: 600px;
    position: relative;
}

.map-container:before {
  border-right: 403px solid transparent;
    border-top: 403px solid #F4775C;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 1px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="map-container">
<img src="http://knowkalpesh.in/img/map/knowkalpesh-map.png" alt="My Address Map">
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify it. The pale red color is slant, isn't it?

Comment: @srishty need slanting not to add a div above the map. You must check how to tilt the map.

Comment: Can you mark answer as correct? So that other can easily find this as correct answer.